# Javascript disable function after 1 click

Tags: javascript, events

I read more than 10 articles, I tried many codes but I did not find a solution, so this is my code I want to disable this function after 1 click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onclick = MyPopUpLink;
function MyPopUpLink() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0] = window.open("https://google.com");
};
</script>
```

Please, this may be similar to many other articles but I could not find a solution, so please help me. Thank You

Comment: Just add `window.onclick = null` to end of function

Comment: I thank you all for help, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `addEventListener` instead, and you can attach the listener with a `once` option, which means it will only run once:

```
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.open("https://google.com");
}, { once: true });
```

(Cannot embed snippet due to SO's sandboxing issues, but you can see it on [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/v6krzm5g/))

Note that it's much easier to refer to `document.body` than to `getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`, and assigning a `window.open` to `document.body` won't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

just do re-assignment.

```
window.onclick = function() {
 document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0] = window.open("https://google.com");
 window.onclick = ""
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by defining a function that handles the open window behaviour, and then binding that function to the `click` event for the document's `body` element.

To prevent the event from firing a second time, call:

```
document.body.removeEventListener('click', onClickBody);
```

from within the handler to "deregister" that click event which prevents the popup behaviour from being executed on subsequent clicks:

```js
function onClickBody() {
  
  // Cannot call this in snippet
  // window.open("https://google.com");
  alert('window.open("https://google.com");')
  
  // Remove this event handler to prevent the event handler from being
  // fired again on subsequent body clicks
  document.body.removeEventListener('click', onClickBody);
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', onClickBody);
```

```html
Body fires click once
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener that fires once with the native "addEventListener" like this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // your code here
}, { once:true })
```

You can read more about addEventListener and its options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Syntax

If you wan't to achieve the same behaviour with jquery (you tagged your post so), there is the "one" function: http://api.jquery.com/one/

You use it like this

```
$(document.body).one('click', function(){
    // your code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a variable that updates after the function is runned for the first time.(this works for any function)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var enabled = true;
   window.onclick = MyPopUpLink;
   function MyPopUpLink() {
        if(enabled == true){
          document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0] = window.open("https://google.com");
          enabled = false;
        }
   };
</script>
```

The other option is to use `addEventListener` event without any function.
But this works for events only.

```
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.open("https://google.com");
}, {once: true});
```

You could also use the inline event `onclick="MyPopUpLink()"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

```
let counter1=0;
window.onclick = MyPopUpLink;
function MyPopUpLink() {
if(counter1===0){
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0] = window.open("https://google.com");
  counter1++
}
}
```